# Cannot connect remotely to MongoDB despite adding local IP to mongod.conf

Tags: database, mongodb, ip, remote-access, mongodb-compass

I have an issue with establishing a remote connection to MongoDB running on a VPS. I have followed instructions on editing the mongod.conf to bind my IP.

The network section looks like this:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

The latter IP is my local machine which I am trying to access MongoDB on using Compass.

I have also tried surrounding the list in `[]`, but it does not work. I am restarting the mongo service after each change like so:

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

When I try to run `mongo` after adding the new comma-separated IP to the `bindIp` I receive the following error.

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

When I edit the `mongo.conf` to remove the second IP, `mongo` works and I can use the shell.

I have also created a new user in the MongoDB admin to use as credentials in Compass which I am using to try to connect in Compass.

This is what the user looks like in the admin `system.users` collection.

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.newAdmin",
    "userId" : UUID("9b5c9a51-de6b-4e55-a2bc-3ae92d89993c"),
    "user" : "newAdmin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "credentials" : { ... },
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

The connection string in Compass:

```
mongodb://username:password@<vps-ip>:27017/?authSource=admin&readPreference=primary&ssl=false
```

I have seen that replacing `bindIp` with `0.0.0.0` works, but I am not comfortable with that from a security point of view.

If anyone can help with a solution to securely and easily establishing a remote connection I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Security should be provided with a network and/or local firewall, not by setting IP's in `bindIp`

Answer (score 2):

`bindIp` is a list of network interfaces to listen **on mongodb server**, not a list of client IPs.

Assuming mongodb is running on *nix system, list available interfaces in terminal:

```
ifconfig
```

or

```
ip -c a
```

depending on distributive

there is at least 1 virtual interface "lo" `inet 127.0.0.1` - the local loop, and at least 1 physical interface associated with the network card - something like "eth0", "wifi0", etc. Numbers may differ, as well as number of interfaces.
Get the IP from `inet` property and add it to mongodb config.

Let me stress, `bindIp` does not limit who can connect to mongo, only what networks mongo listens on, so if there are only 2 interfaces - lo and eth0 there is no difference between listing both of them in the config, or using 0.0.0.0.

If you want to limit traffic from specific **client** IP - use system firewall.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still not sure how to implement it though. If I leave the `mongo.conf` as it is with `bindIp: 127.0.0.1` and set my `ufw` firewall to allow a specific ip, should I be able to connect to my MongoDB securely?

Comment: I figured it out thanks! It's working now. I just need to ensure that the `ufw` is only allowing connections from specific IPs and blocking all others now.